# Cleaning up MicroSD/Storage

Tags: android

Are there any tools for cleaning up the storage on Android phones? Apps seem to be making folders everywhere and even when they are removed the folders still stay...

Can't tell which app uses or needs what directory, and manual removal feels like such a pain...

Comment: There's no app for that, you need to manual delete the directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android, applications are isolated into different processes with different uid. For each application, there is a data directory, generally under /data directory, to store the application data. The directory is unreadable for other non-root process. So if your device hasn't been rooted, there is no application can delete those data folders owned by other applications.

However when you remove an application, Android will remove the dir created for that application. I think what you really cares is the data under /sdcard. Any application that has been granted the android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE can r/w the sdcard.

Solutions:

1. Create your own application, you can remove any files on sdcard as you want by requesting android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.
2. Existing sdcard cleaning app: [Forever Gone (SD Card Cleaner)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kovit.p.forevergone&hl=en)
3. If your device are rooted already, then you will be able to remove any application dirs. Many apps like [SD Maid - System cleaning tool](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm&hl=en) are intended for this.

Comment: Ah.. SD Maid seems to do the trick